# If I don't nest the if/else statements, the code doesn't work. Why do I have to nest?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested

## overview

I am learning JavaScript and have an exercise that combines accessing object properties, loops, and if/else statements.

My code doesn't work.  The  solution (which works) nests the if/else statements, but otherwise seems to be the same code.  I don't understand the difference.

## exercise instructions

- The function should check if name is an actual contact's firstName and the given property (prop) is a property of that contact.
- If both are true, then return the "value" of that property.
- If name does not correspond to any contacts then return "No such contact"
- If prop does not correspond to any valid properties of a contact found to match name then return "No such property"

## the given array

```
 var contacts = [
      {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
      }
    ];
```

## my code

(which doesn't work)

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop){

for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contacts[i][prop];
    } else if (contacts[i].firstName !== name) {
        return "No such contact";
    } else {
        return "No such property";
    }
}

lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes"); 
//should return ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
```

## exercise solution

(which does work)

```
for (var x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++){
    if (contacts[x].firstName === name) {
        if (contacts[x].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            return contacts[x][prop];
        } else {
            return "No such property";
        }
    }
}
return "No such contact";

lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes"); 
//returns ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
```

## why?

I expected that the two solutions would both work, but mine does not. Why?

Comment: These two code blocks do not do the same thing for instance look at where you are checking for hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you immediately return once the name does not equal the given name.

So lets run your program.

i = 0, we compare contacts[0].name = Akira with Sherlock. Does the name equal Sherlock? No it does not. So your first if  `if (contacts[i].firstName === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {` condition fails. We move onto the next condition, your else if:

```
else if (contacts[i].firstName !== name) {
        return "No such contact";
```

And this condition is true. So we immediately return.

Do you see how your code prematurely returns? It does not allow us to actually move forward.

What you need to do is place the return outside of your for loop. I won't give you the exact solution because this is clearly a homework solution. But the hint should move you forward.

Answer (score 3):

In the solution, you look for a contact with the matching name. Once you find the contact with the provided name, you return, which means the loop ends (possibly early). What you return depends on if the prop exists or not but you DO return.

In your attempt, you return on the first iteration of the loop every time. Here's what your code should have looked like if you wanted to keep the same behavior:

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop){

    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].firstName === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            return contacts[i][prop];
        } else if (contacts[i].firstName === name && !contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            return "No such property";
        }
    }

    return "No such contact";
}
```

You can see how contacts[i].firstName gets checked twice in this case. That's because you don't want to exit the loop with a return if you haven't found a contact with the given name yet. Nesting cleans this up by reduce duplicate checks for complex conditional expressions.

Comment: Actually, this code does not fulfill all the requirements.  I tried using it, and the feedback was that  `lookUpProfile("Bob", "number");`   should return "No such contact", but does not.

Comment: You are correct, I forgot the second part of the condition in the "else if". Updated for the sake of future answer seekers.

Answer (score 0):

I realized later  that part of the problem was that I got lazy with the last part of my conditional statement:

`else {
    return "No such property";
}`

If I had instead written out

`if (contacts[x].firstName === name && !(contacts[x].hasOwnProperty(prop))`

to meet this requirement:

- If prop does not correspond to any valid properties of a contact found to match name then return "No such property"

I would then have seen that nesting if statements would be less repetitive.

The other issue is that last "lazy" else statement provided a default, and always ending the function with contacts[0].  That meant that only contacts[0] would ever be passed through the function; no further iterations with contacts[1]. contacts[2], etc.  (Good learning experience!)